# Should I put all of my Data Service logic for Firebase in 1 file?

Tags: ios, model-view-controller

For example I created a file called DataService which is a singleton that takes care of all the firebase logic such as storing, fetching, deleting data. However is it wise to store all of my logic in here or is it best to separate it? For example should I not have a Service class that takes care of all the User related data logic (insert/edit/delete/update), and then another Service class for Posts (insert/edit/delete/update)..etc and so forth. The only other cases I have another service class is for FirebaseStorage, FirebaseAuth..etc

So far all my logic for data handling in firebase is in DataService.swift file

Comment: Create a base class which you extend based on your entity, you could look into generics. So you instantiate your generic class with your Entity type you want to manage and do your thang.

This case you won't have specific User logic but abstract logic for every class. As far as I know this would work fine with firebase.

Comment: Interesting, I was thinking of extending the base class so the child class can just use the parent's references to the firebase paths, and I didn't think of Generics there, I have to look more into those. thank you